# How to construct a SAMLObject from a SAML message string?

Tags: saml, opensaml

I need to construct an instance of SAMLObject from a SAML message string. After having a look at the OpenSAML APIs, I can't figure how it can be done.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually by using an UnmarshallerFactory to get a Unmarshaller for your type of SAML message that can be used to parse a XMLObject from a XML element. Some thing like this

```
factory = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport().getUnmarshallerFactory()
unmarshaller = factory.getUnmarshaller(Assertion.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME)
XMLobject = unmarshaller.unmarshall(Element element)
```

This XML object can then be cast to the actual SAML object like a Assertion object

This could atleast be done in opensaml 2.

However what you should really look into is using the available encoders to handle the low level message parsing and handling.

Here is an example on my blog on how to use encoders to send a authnrequst
http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2016/08/signing-and-sending-authnrequests-in.html

The encoder handles signing converting the SAML object to text and sending the message.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Based on your answer, I figure out the code. BTW, there are some syntax errors in your code sample.

Comment: I can't find the  XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport class in OpenSAML 2. I add my code segment to illustrate how I write the code.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figure out a solution:

```
DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
UnmarshallerFactory factory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
Element element = getElement(); // reading a XML file into a Input Stream
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = factory.getUnmarshaller(element);
XMLObject obj = unmarshaller.unmarshall(element);
```