# Converting assertion to string in OpenSAML 4

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I am trying to follow this example:  [How to create a valid SAML 2.0 Assertion with OpenSAML library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579742/how-to-create-a-valid-saml-2-0-assertion-with-opensaml-library-in-java) and trying to create a SAML response. The code shown is for an older version of OpenSAML. I am using OpenSAML 4.1.1. Apparently XMLHelper is no longer in v.4. I have searched high and low and not found a solution, at least one that makes sense where I can convert the assertion into a string.

Below is the code I have right out of the sample:

```
        SAMLInputContainer input = new SAMLInputContainer();
        input.strIssuer = "http://synesty.com";
        input.strNameID = "UserJohnSmith";
        input.strNameQualifier = "My Website";
        input.sessionId = "abcdedf1234567";

        Map<String,String> customAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        customAttributes.put("FirstName", "John");
        customAttributes.put("LastName", "Smith");
        customAttributes.put("Email", "john.smith@yahoo.com");
        customAttributes.put("PhoneNumber", "76373898998");
        customAttributes.put("Locality", "USA");
        customAttributes.put("Username", "John.Smith");

        input.attributes = customAttributes;

        Assertion assertion = GenSAMLAssertion.buildDefaultAssertion(input);
        AssertionMarshaller marshaller = new AssertionMarshaller();
        assert assertion != null;
        Element plaintextElement = marshaller.marshall(assertion);
        String originalAssertionString = XMLHelper.nodeToString(plaintextElement);

        System.out.println("Assertion String: " + originalAssertionString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SerializeSupport class is now used to print XML in OpenSAML.

```
String originalAssertionString = SerializeSupport.prettyPrintXML(plaintextElement)
```

As for more current sample code for OpenSAML 4 I have a [ongoing series on my blog](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/tags/opensaml4/). As well as accompanying [source samples on my Github](https://github.com/rasmusson/OpenSAML-sample-code)

A few years ago I also wrote a [book on OpenSAML 3](https://payhip.com/b/41Tw). It has not been updated but there are very few changes between 3 and 4.

Comment: Well, that was simple!  I've tried studying all of your material (not the book, yet) but my head was spinning. Now, if I could just solve the change for the builderFactory.

Comment: Ok, have a look on my helper class OpenSAML utils here https://github.com/rasmusson/OpenSAML-sample-code/blob/main/getting-started-authnrequest/src/main/java/com/samlsecurity/opensamlSamples/gettingStartedAuthnrequest/OpenSAMLUtils.java. The method buildSAMLObject gets a build builder and builds a object. If you think the answer answered your question, please mark it as correct

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko forgot to tag you above

Comment: What about converting a string into an assertion object? @StefanRasmusson

Comment: This is usually managed by using an encoder. Example https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/01/redirect-with-authnrequest.html. But you can do it yourself using an unmarshaller. This is an old example I have in this answer. not sure what the current syntax is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375807/how-to-construct-a-samlobject-from-a-saml-message-string